# How to solve Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline()? readline library not found?

Tags: php, xampp

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. And XAMPP for linux 1.7.7.

When I code in php with and call the readline function I get this error message?
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline()"

I recently found the below thread which pointed out the name of the package that contained the desired readline:
[How to solve configure: error: readline library not found?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89389/how-to-solve-configure-error-readline-library-not-found)

I went ahead and installed # apt-get install libreadline6. But this didnt seem to make a difference. I still get the same error message: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline()". Was the thread missing further steps? Can anyone help me?

I am new to Ubuntu.

```
<?php

echo "Simple menu \n" ;

echo "1. Play Sports \n";
echo "2. Play Strategy games \n";

$userInput = readline('Enter something here: ');

?>
```

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: @Devav2 The PHP version I use is: PHP 5.3.8

Answer (score 2):

The default php builds on ubuntu use [**libedit**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php/php5-cli) and instead of **readline**. (Due to some licensing issue)

To get the readline support you can download the source and build it

Comment: any suggestions on how to build it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found this [link](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/compiling-and-building-php-53-on-ubuntu) online. This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked just fine for me on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Install the libreadline6-dev package.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
```

Comment: This is only useful if you are actually building a program with readline support. Just installing it does not magically make PHP support the readline extension.

Comment: @green7 If you read the beginning of the thread, I did mention that  I did install it using: sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev.

Comment: @Lekensteyn How do I build a program with readline support? Doesn't the little program in the initial thread count as a program with readline support?

Comment: @SirBT No, you didn't.

Comment: @SirBT Only if PHP was compiled with readline support enabled. In that case the binary would depend on `libreadline.so.6` and therefore requiring the `libreadline6` package.